# Specify the date format in XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I want to use a Date in `XMLGregorianCalendar` format for sending to a web service. The web service expects information in `yyyy-dd-mm` format. I use the below code to create an `XMLGregorianCalendar` and send it to web service.

```
Date dob = null;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

try {
    XMLGregorianCalendar date2;
    dob = df.parse("13/06/1983");

    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTimeInMillis(dob.getTime());
    date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
    System.out.println(date2);
}
catch(DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately I always get the date as `1983-06-13T00:00:00.000-04:00`. Time is also getting included in the output. Is it possible to get only the date? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 34):

you don't need to specify a "SimpleDateFormat", it's simple:
You must do specify the constant "DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED" where you don't want to show

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(new Date());
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

Comment: getting "javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found" error above code. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: As of Java 8 you should use: DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);

Comment: @leccionesonline I beg to differ. As of Java 8 you should not be using `GregorianCalendar` at all, or at least only for like `DatatypeFactory.newInstance() .newXMLGregorianCalendar(yourGregorianCalendar)`. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). `GregorianCalendar` and related classes had severe design issues and are outdated since Java 8.

Answer (score 17):

Much simpler using only SimpleDateFormat, without passing all the parameters individual:

```
    String FORMATER = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMATER);

    Date date = new Date();
    XMLGregorianCalendar gDateFormatted =
        DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(format.format(date));
```

Full example [here](http://www.admfactory.com/how-to-format-xmlgregoriancalendar/).

**Note:** This is working only to remove the last 2 fields: milliseconds and timezone or to remove the entire time component using formatter `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Don’t treat `Z` as a literal. It’s an offset of zero from UTC, which is unlikely to be correct.

Answer (score 16):

Yeah Got it...

```
Date dob=null;
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dob=df.parse( "13/06/1983" );
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(dob);
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

This will give it in correct format.

Comment: Why the ```+1```at ```cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1```?

Comment: In java.util.Calendar January is represented as 0, so every month is shifted by 1. Don't ask me why... People recommend [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) where it fits. @Manu

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy way for any format. Just change it to required format string

```
XMLGregorianCalendar gregFmt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
System.out.println(gregFmt);
```

Comment: Easiest solution!

Comment: very simple and fantastic solution. thanks

Answer (score 3):

There isn’t really an ideal conversion, but I would like to supply a couple of options.

**java.time**

First, you should use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for parsing and holding your date. Avoid `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` since they have design problems and also are long outdated. The latter in particular is notoriously troublesome.

```
    DateTimeFormatter originalDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    
    String dateString = "13/06/1983";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, originalDateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

The output is:

> 1983-06-13

Do you need to go any further? `LocalDate.toString()` produces the format you asked about.

**Format and parse**

Assuming that you do require an `XMLGregorianCalendar` the first and easy option for converting is:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(date.toString());
    System.out.println(xmlDate);
```

> 1983-06-13

Formatting to a string and parsing it back feels like a waste to me, but as I said, it’s easy and I don’t think that there are any surprises about the result being as expected.

**Pass year, month and day of month individually**

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(date.getYear(), date.getMonthValue(),
                    date.getDayOfMonth(), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

The result is the same as before. We need to make explicit that we don’t want a time zone offset (this is what `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED` specifies). In case someone is wondering, both `LocalDate` and `XMLGregorianCalendar` number months the way humans do, so there is no adding or subtracting 1.

**Convert through GregorianCalendar**

I only show you this option because I somehow consider it the official way: convert `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime`, then to `GregorianCalendar` and finally to `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    GregorianCalendar gregCal = GregorianCalendar.from(dateTime);
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregCal);
    xmlDate.setTime(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED,
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, null);
    xmlDate.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

I like the conversion itself since we neither need to use strings nor need to pass individual fields (with care to do it in the right order). What I don’t like is that we have to pass a time of day and a time zone offset and then wipe out those fields manually afterwards.