# String date to xmlgregoriancalendar conversion

Tags: java, string, date

I have written this function :

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getXMLGregorianCalendar(String date) throws OmniException{
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalender=null;
    GregorianCalendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
    calender.setTime(Util.stringToJavaDate(date));
    xmlCalender = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calender);
    return xmlCalender;
}

public static Date  stringToJavaDate(String sDate)  throws OmniException{
    Date date=null;
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(sDate);        
    return date;  
}
```

When i am passing date as `"2014-01-07"` am getting output date as `2014-01-06T18:30:00:000Z`
where i am going wrong ?
also what to do if I want to get only `2014-01-06T18:30:00` and `2014-01-06T18:30:00Z`
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you setting Locale properly?

Comment: i am setting it to locale.ENGLISH in simpledateformat ; is it right ?? please guide me!! :)

Comment: You have to set it to your country's locale not just english. Example is given here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html

Comment: Got some help from this :
Specify the date format in XMLGregorianCalendar[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060161/specify-the-date-format-in-xmlgregoriancalendar

Comment: FYI, the classes shown in this Question are now outdated, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found the solution as below.... posting it as it could help somebody else too :)

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("2014-04-24 11:15:00");

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);

XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal =  DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);

System.out.println(xmlGregCal);
```

Output:

2014-04-24T11:15:00.000+02:00

Comment: after you've parsed Date and set GregorianCalendar's time, you can just pass calendar as argument to newXMLGregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendar cal)

Answer (score 37):

For me the most elegant solution is this one:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-01-07");
```

Using Java 8.

Extended example:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-01-07");
System.out.println(result.getDay());
System.out.println(result.getMonth());
System.out.println(result.getYear());
```

This prints out:

```
7
1
2014
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful for me who has little experience with the xml types.

Comment: This solution is helpful only for the XML date format as specified in XML Schema: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation

Comment: Does that work if you have date and time? Say, in this format: "2014-01-07 23:47"

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

- Use modern *java.time* classes as much as possible, rather than the terrible legacy classes.
- Always specify your desired/expected time zone or offset-from-UTC rather than rely implicitly on JVM’s current default.

Example code (without exception-handling):

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = 
    DatatypeFactory                           // Data-type converter.
    .newInstance()                            // Instantiate a converter object.
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(                 // Converter going from `GregorianCalendar` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`.
        GregorianCalendar.from(               // Convert from modern `ZonedDateTime` class to legacy `GregorianCalendar` class.
            LocalDate                         // Modern class for representing a date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone.
            .parse( "2014-01-07" )            // Parsing strings in standard ISO 8601 format is handled by default, with no need for custom formatting pattern. 
            .atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )   // Determine the first moment of the day as seen in UTC. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
        )                                     // Returns a `GregorianCalendar` object.
    )                                         // Returns a `XMLGregorianCalendar` object.
;
```

## Parsing date-only input string into an object of `XMLGregorianCalendar` class

Avoid the terrible legacy date-time classes whenever possible, such as `XMLGregorianCalendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `Calendar`, and `Date`. Use only modern *java.time* classes.

When presented with a string such as `"2014-01-07"`, parse as a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2014-01-07" )
```

To get a date with time-of-day, assuming you want the first moment of the day, specify a time zone. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day, as it is not always 00:00:00.0 in some zones on some dates.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2014-01-07" )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
```

This returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
        LocalDate
        .parse( "2014-01-07" )
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
;
```

> zdt.toString() = 2014-01-07T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

But apparently, you want the start-of-day as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). So we specify `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant as our `ZoneId` argument.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
        LocalDate
        .parse( "2014-01-07" )
        .atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )
;
```

> zdt.toString() = 2014-01-07T00:00Z

The `Z` on the end means UTC (an offset of zero), and is pronounced “Zulu”.

If you must work with legacy classes, convert to [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), a subclass of [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

> gc.toString() = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1389052800000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=2,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=7,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]

Apparently, you really need an object of the legacy class [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html). If the calling code cannot be updated to use *java.time*, convert.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = 
        DatatypeFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newXMLGregorianCalendar( gc ) 
;
```

Actually, that code requires a try-catch.

```
try
{
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc =
            DatatypeFactory
                    .newInstance()
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar( gc );
}
catch ( DatatypeConfigurationException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> xgc = 2014-01-07T00:00:00.000Z

Putting that all together, with appropriate exception-handling.

```
// Given an input string such as "2014-01-07", return a `XMLGregorianCalendar` object
// representing first moment of the day on that date as seen in UTC. 
static public XMLGregorianCalendar getXMLGregorianCalendar ( String input )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( input );
    if( input.isBlank() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Received empty/blank input string for date argument. Message # 11818896-7412-49ba-8f8f-9b3053690c5d." ) ; }
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = null;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = null;

    try
    {
        zdt =
                LocalDate
                        .parse( input )
                        .atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC );
    }
    catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Faulty input string for date does not comply with standard ISO 8601 format. Message # 568db0ef-d6bf-41c9-8228-cc3516558e68." );
    }

    GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt );
    try
    {
        xgc =
                DatatypeFactory
                        .newInstance()
                        .newXMLGregorianCalendar( gc );
    }
    catch ( DatatypeConfigurationException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Objects.requireNonNull( xgc );
    return xgc ;
}
```

Usage.

```
String input = "2014-01-07";
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = App.getXMLGregorianCalendar( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "xgc = " + xgc );
```

> xgc = 2014-01-07T00:00:00.000Z

## Modern date-time classes versus legacy

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Date-time != String

Do not conflate a date-time value with its textual representation. We parse strings to get a date-time object, and we ask the date-time object to generate a string to represent its value. The date-time object has no ‘format’, only strings have a format.

So shift your thinking into two separate modes: model and presentation. Determine the date-value you have in mind, applying appropriate time zone, as the model. When you need to display that value, generate a string in a particular format as expected by the user.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The Question and other Answers all use old troublesome date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

Your input string `"2014-01-07"` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The `T` in the middle separates date portion from time portion.

The `Z` on the end is short for Zulu and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Fortunately, the java.time classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2014-01-07" ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2014-01-07

## Start of day `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to see the first moment of that day, specify a `ZoneId` time zone to get a moment on the timeline, a `ZonedDateTime`. The time zone is crucial because the date varies around the globe by zone. A few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

Never assume the day begins at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means the day may begin at another time-of-day such as 01:00:00. Let java.time determine the first moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2014-01-07T00:00:00Z

For your desired format, generate a string using the predefined formatter [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) and then replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
                   .replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

> 2014-01-07 00:00:00

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: This has nothing to do with converting string representations of `java.time` objects into `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 You were correct. So I revamped the first section to address the Question head-on. Thank you for the criticism. The Answer is much better now.

Comment: @George That appreciation should be aimed at [Stephen Colebourne](https://uk.linkedin.com/in/stephencolebourne), the man who led [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and who led its predecessor, [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). He also leads the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) and [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) projects.

Answer (score 2):

```
GregorianCalendar c = GregorianCalendar.from((LocalDate.parse("2016-06-22")).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```