# Java DateTimeFormatter parse YearMonth with offset

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, timezone-offset, date-parsing

I'm having problems with parsing a special string representing an year and a month with an offset like this: `2014-08+03:00`.

The desired output is an `YearMonth`.

I have tested creating a custom `DateTimeFormatter` with all kind of patterns, but it fails and a `DateTimeParseException` is thrown.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMZ");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = YearMonth.parse(month, formatter);
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from(temporalAccessor);
```

What is the correct pattern for this particular format?

Is it even possible to create a `DateTimeFormatter` that parses this `String`, or should I manipulate the String `"2014-08+03:00"` and remove the offset manually to `"2014-08"`, and then parse it into a `YearMonth` (or to some other `java.time` class)?

**Edit:**

I further investigated the API and its .xsd schema-file where the attribute is listed as `<xs:attribute name="month" type="xs:gYearMonth"/>` where the namespace is `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

So apparently the type of the attribute is [DataTypeConstans.GYEARMONTH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#getXMLSchemaType()) where "2014-08+03:00" is a valid format.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105869/6527865) answer explains how to convert a `String` to a `XMLGregorianCalendar`, from where it is possible to convert to an `YearMonth` via an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-08+03:00");
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.from(result.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toOffsetDateTime());
```

However I am still curious if it possible to parse the string `"2014-08+03:00"` directly to an `YearMonth` only using a custom `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: A `YearMonth` contains no timezone information...

Comment: Yes I know, and I wonder why the API includes the offset in it and I do not need the offset myself. @assylias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct pattern for the offset `+03:00` is `XXX` (check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for details - actually in `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` docs there's a [more detailed explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-)):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMXXX");
String str = "2014-08+03:00";
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(yearMonth);
```

The output will be:

> 2014-08

Comment: That's the one! Now I see that "Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'." Thanks!