# Xmlgregoriancalendar to 'yyyy-MM-dd' while generating XML SOAP request

Tags: xml, soap, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a WSDL of a soap web service. I generated the source files from the WSDL using wsimport command and added it in my java application code.

In the WSDL there is a date field which is of the type XMLGregorianCalendar. The tricky part here is that when the XML is generated, the format is some default format. Here is the part of the XML request.

<NeedDate>2015-04-06-04:00</NeedDate>

As per the requirement, it have to convert it to 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. 
My question is how to specify the date format to be used during XML generation.

Thanks.

Comment: Found a similar question and that solved my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060161/specify-the-date-format-in-xmlgregoriancalendar

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly your question, but the format of XMLGregorianCalendar depends the way how it was instantiated.

For example, if you create the instance using `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate([...])`, the output value will be in format **yyyy-MM-dd**.

Another ways to create an instance of XMLGregorianCalendar are:

- `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar([...])`
- `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarTime([...])`

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks bruno, I found a similar question and that solved my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060161/specify-the-date-format-in-xmlgregoriancalendar